# Как лучше обновлять существующие данные в VirtualTreeView?

Tags: delphi

Всем привет. В программе часто обновляется VirtualTreeView. Интервал обновления около 100мс. Но, иногда начинаются мерцания. При выставлении интервала на больший они успешно пропадают. Вопрос: как наиболее эффективно обновлять данные в VirtualTreeView?

Процедура обновления данных:

```
procedure TDownloadBar.AddInfo(VST: TBaseVirtualTree; N: Integer;
Inf, Path: string);
var
  Data: PTreeData;
  Node: PVirtualNode;
begin
  Node := NodeByIndex(VST, N);

  if not Assigned(Node) then
    Exit;

  Data := VST.GetNodeData(Node);

  Data.Inf := Inf;
  Data.Path := Path;

  VST.InvalidateNode(Node);
end;
```

Функция NodeByIndex:

```
function TDownloadBar.NodeByIndex(const VST: TBaseVirtualTree;
  const anIndex: Integer): PVirtualNode;
var
  Count: Integer;
  Node: PVirtualNode;
begin
  Node := VST.GetFirst(False);
  Count := 0;

  while (Node <> nil) and (Count < anIndex) do
  begin
    Node := VST.GetNext(Node);
    inc(Count);
  end;

  Result := Node;
end;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сам VirtualTreeView не пользовался, но по аналогии можно кое-что придумать:

**1)** Обычно от мерцания спасает двойная буферизация *DoubleBuffered* (если, конечно, делфи новая).

**2)**Как у обычного TreeView в TTreeNodes есть *BeginUpdate* и *EndUpdate*, возможно есть и здесь.
Это тоже может помочь.

Comment: BeginUpdate и EndUpdate есть оно и помогло)